# Efficient look-up without the use of hashes?

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, data-structures, hash

So I'm writing [this Python program](https://github.com/rhgrant10/Pants) that implements the ACO algorithm. Briefly, when an ant goes to make it's next move, it knows (1) which node it is on and (2) which nodes it still needs to visit. With that information, it inspects the properties of each `Edge` in order to choose which `Node` it should visit next. So I have the ant use that information to look up the corresponding `Edge`.

Internally, I'm using a `dict` to map `Node` pairs to `Edge` instances. Originally, I was okay with the restriction that a `Node` must be hashable. However, it has always been a restriction I didn't particularly enjoy imposing, and I'd like to eliminate it if at all possible.

Currently, I have a `Node` class that implements `__hash__` by hashing a `frozenset` of the object's `__dict__.items()`, but this still produces errors for cases involving mutable values (and it is, by far, my least favorite class - ever).

So far I've thought about using a 2D matrix, but it may often be the case that the `Edge`s are few compared to the `Node`s, which would result in a sparse matrix, and therefore much wasted space. I've thought about using a simple list, but then I loose the ability to do super-fast look-ups.

#### TL;DR:

*What data structures can I use (preferred if the implementation is solid) or self-implement that will grant fast look-ups of `Edge`s from pairs of `Node`s without involving the generation of hashes?*

Comment: Do you need to look up edges from a *pair* of nodes, or do you only need to iterate over all edges starting from a given node? You demand the former, but your use case description above only seems to do `for neighbor in current.neighbors: ...`

Comment: No that's the situation I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to have to iterate through all the edges, which I why I opted for look up via a dictionary.

Comment: So have an array of nodes, and give the ant *node indexes*. Then your key becomes two integers. Or a single 64-bit integer with one index in the high 32 bits and one index in the low 32 bits. It's still hash based, but it's dead simple to implement.

Comment: @JimMischel Brilliant. Exactly what I was after. I'm even a little ashamed I failed to see that simple solution, but I know it's too much focus and too little sleep, haha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than hashing the nodes directly, create an array of nodes and give the ant node indexes. Your key becomes two integers or perhaps a single 64-bit integer with one index in the high 32 bits and one index in the low 32 bits. It's still hash based, but it's dead simple to implement.

Comment: Implemented! And it significantly increased the overall performance, so thank you!